# using php in css to target a unique object class

Tags: php, html, css

i have a page that automatically adds a number to a objects class name like this

```
<a href="#" class="clickBtn'.$clickid.'" >click</a>
```

$clickid is a number being successfully called from the database, so  may be class="clickBtn296"

the next  in the series may be class="clickBtn273"

how can i target all of these  by class name, right now im trying everything i can think of, including

```
.clickBtn<?php echo $clickid ?>{
display:block;
}
```

but this isnt working, what can i do?

Comment: You can use `a[class^="clickBtn"]`.

Comment: this only targets the first one, when there are many of them on the page

Comment: No.This Selects every <a> element whose href attribute value begins with "clickBtn" - @peter

Comment: only the first one shows any action, i want them all to be controlled independently of eachother.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another class by giving space.

```
<a href="#" class="myButtons clickBtn'.$clickid.'" >click</a>
```

Then add common css to target that class

```
.myButtons{
display:block;
}
```

Comment: still only targets the first <a> in the list, i have many many many to target individually with the same style but with different names

Comment: If you want to bind click to all then bind click to myButtons and then you will get clicked element in "this"

Comment: not working yet, is there any more code i can provide to help solve this?

Comment: Can you provide complete code that you are trying. Javascript as well as php